# Local Domain LDAP certificate

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, ldap, certificate, fsmo

I'm really new to certificates, I had a windows server 2012 R2  we did an in-place upgrade from 2008 R2, lets call that ADServer. It was the AD DC and everything was fine. I bought new servers and added them to the domain as AD DC's and AD everything was replicating. After giving FSMO roles to the new server (DC-01) I noticed a couple of issues. First, when trying to add a new computer to the domain, I would get an error:

The query for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.com
The following domain controllers were identified by the query:
ADServer.domain.com (old server)
DC-01.domain.com (new server 01)
DC-02.domain.com (new server 02)
However, no domain controllers could be contacted.
Common causes of this error include:

- Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.
- Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.

Also, I noticed before when we looked at the network for client computers, it would say "domain.com", now it just says "network".

Then I realized that I had Meraki VPN auth with AD and now its throwing an error "ldap_start_tls:Server is unavailable" Meraki told me it's a certificate singing issue. I'm thinking that might have something to do with our other issues as well.

Any and all input is appreciated, I really need to figure this out.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I looked at the (A) and (AAAA) records and everything looks fine.

Comment: Smells like DNS. Post `ipconfig /all` from all DCs and any problematic client.

Comment: I agree with @Crypt32, smells like DNS. Nevertheless, if you want to check for SSL/TLS problems, doing an `openssl connect ...` against the machine in question is often very insightful.